# Maven delete external files

Tags: maven, file-io

I am using Eclipse/maven plugin.
I want to delete external file with aboslute path, i have following example but it claims to delete only relative files which resides inside the project

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>some/relative/path</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.tmp</include>
                                <include>**/*.log</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/important.log</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/another-important.log</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Why do you want to delete files outside of the Maven project ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <followSymLinks>false</followSymLinks>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
            <directory>D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.24\webapps\cat360-web-1.0.0</directory>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This will make your build depending on your machine with exactly this location of folders..That's bad practice. Will never run on a CI solution. BTW: Never use back-slashes.

Comment: @khmarbaise It may be best practice, but it's also the answer to the question posed :-)

Comment: And where this is diffrent from question example? The path `some/relative/path` was not proper?